# Is there any difference in using Hibernate with Spring as compared to Hibernate alone?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

So far we have been using Hibernate alone -   I am moving to JPA. Spring is used for MVC in our projects.  They are used completely separately.

I checked the new Spring 4.0 Petclinic project with Hibernate JPA implementation (https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic.git).   Again I do not see that influence of Spring on the Hibernate code.  For example JpaPetRepositoryImpl is used without Spring except the @Repository annotation. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of Spring is to be as unintrusive to your code as possible, you should see as little of spring as possible in your code. Basically that is the whole point and aim of Spring.

When you normally use hibernate without spring you would have some kind of singleton which constructs the hibernate `SessionFactory`.

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sf;

    static {
            sf = ew Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static getSessionFactory() {
        return sf;
    }

}
```

The next thing you would see is code that is filling up with calls to `HibernateUtils.getSesionFactory()`. You would manually need to create your `Session` and start/commit transactions.

```
public void save(Entity e) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
         session.save(e);
         tx.commit();
    } catch (HIbernateException he) {
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

However this code is bad due to 2 reasons. The first you are manually managing your transactions, which after a while becomes a pain, you want to use declarative transaction management. The second you are managing transactions at the wrong layer, transactions should be managed at the service layer. Now to make that possible you would have to get the `SessionFactory` in your Service layer, which would suddenly turns data access layer into a leaky abstraction.

Spring can help you with both things, it can do declarative tx management and hide the fact that you are using Hibernate, not making it a leaky abstraction.

```
@Inject
private SessionFactory sf;

public void save(Entity e) {
    sf.getCurrentSession().save(e);
}
```

This would be the same in a Spring way. The transaction would be started at the service level (with a `@Transactional` or `@TransactionAttributes` annotation).

For JPA this is more or less the same, however as JPA is a standard Spring tries to follow those as much as possible. So plain JPA code and JPA code in Spring doesn't differ that much (unless you are using JPA in a standalone application and not a JEE container, than the JPA code would be like the hibernate code).

Answer (score 1):

one of the big advantages is declarative transaction management using @Transactional annotation, where Spring manages the transaction commit/rollback, have a look at this [example](http://simplespringtutorial.com/springDeclarativeTransactions.html).

Answer (score 0):

I like the @PersistenceContext annotation that injects an EntityManager into my Spring beans. If you are familiar with the SoC ideology, it makes everything a lot clearer to use Spring, but some find it confusing and too magic I guess.

I for sure would totally advise you against using hibernate/jpa/persistence manually without any IoC framework.

Comment: What is wrong in using hibernate/jpa/persistence manually? What is different from JPA? Also, the annotation   PersistenceContext is used in PetClinic inside JPA implementation, it is not used in Spring beans.  What is better?

Comment: What I mean by manually is without injection. At first, not so long ago, I thought I was smarter than Spring, and I created everything myself, entityManager, services, DAOs via constructor. Then I needed transactions, so I wrapped every pieces of my code between tx.begin and tx.commit. After a few dozens services, I earned the Unreadable Mess Medal for my code :D Everything got even worse when I started to need to put my service layer into a web application... that's when I snapped and accepted Spring and its method. But maybe that's not exactly your question, I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Spring with declarative transactions requires proxies or byte code transformations. It complicates debugging and  slows down application startup time. There are many ways to avoid this complexity, one of ways is  Command Design pattern:

```
public class Transaction {
    public void execute(Command command) {
      SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
      Session session = sf.openSession();
      try{
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
           command.execute(session); 
           tx.commit();
         } catch (HIbernateException he) {
           tx.rollback();
         }
      }finally{
         session.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Probably you will need "Context" parameter instead of "Session" for "command.execute(context)"  to abstract this design in practice but for example it is more clear to have "Session" parameter. 
Multiple commands can be executed in the same transaction using composite command wrapper. This design pattern can be used to add command validation, security:  "command.isValid(context)", "command.checkPermissions(context)". Many other aspects can be implemented by this simple but powerful design pattern  without dependency on any heavy weight frameworks. You can use this design with Spring too, Spring is fine to configure factories in XML  but I think Spring is too heavy weight and it is too complicated for other use cases.